# explanation of bit array implementation in C-FAQ

Tags: c, bitmap

I was reading the C-FAQ question no: 20.8 which basically deals with bit arrays:

http://c-faq.com/misc/bitsets.html

One of the macros defined looks something like:

```
#define BITNSLOTS(nb) ((nb + CHAR_BIT - 1) / CHAR_BIT)
```

Is this macro meant to calculate the num of elements(or slots) in the char array (each slot = 8 bits) ? I am not sure what this macro is doing, in particular what the purpose of "+CHAR_BIT -1/CHAR_BIT" is. Any clues will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it calculates how many `char`s are needed to hold the bits. The addition stuff is to make it round up.

Answer (score 3):

- It is a way to round up.

If nb is smaller than CHAR_BIT, you'll still need at least one character.

Answer (score 2):

Remember the division is integer division: there's no "... and three eighths". Suppose you want to group into slots of size 6 *(yeah ... I know `CHAR_BIT` is 8 or more)*

- 1 element: 1 slot: `(1 + 6 - 1) / 6 == (6 / 6) == 1`
- ...
- 5 elements: 1 slot: `(5 + 6 - 1) / 6 == (10/6) == 1`
- 6 elements: 1 slot: `(6 + 6 - 1) / 6 == (11 / 6) == 1`
- 7 elements: 2 slots: `(7 + 6 - 1) / 6 == (12 / 6) == 2`
- ...